# Azure Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) change permissions on ADSI Containers without Enterprise / Domain Admin Rights

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, adsi

I need to modify access rights in Azure Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) for a specific container in ADSI.

Usually in an on-prem Active Directory this is possible with having the correct access rights on an object and changing the Control Access Right (ACE) in the Access Control Lists (ACL) of the object. This usually means I need Enterprise / Domain Admin Rights in the first palace to modify the object rights.

In Azure Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) Microsoft limits the environment by the following: Domain Administrator and Enterprise Administrator privileges aren't available.
The only way to administer the domain is the usage of users in the Group "AAD DC Administrators" which does not have access to the Container Rights:
[Screenshot of the Container ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpuXd.png)

Is there a way to modify the permission on the ADSI Object somehow without the Enterprise / Domain Admin Rights? Or is there a way of setting additional permissions directly through Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD DS is offered as PaaS, and therefore it's only natural that Microsoft locks out what you can do with it. If you don't have the permission, then no, can't be done.

If this is something you really need, go for a DS inside a VM.